# Estimate weights of individuals based on partially observed data

Tags: r, weights

I can observe the sales $y$  in a set of stores $i$ for some products $j$.

I want to estimate the share or the weight of each store. My main issue is that I don't observe all the sales data $y_{ij}$ and the observe/not-observe function doesn't follow any logic/distribution.

An example of my question in $\textsf{R}$ would look like:

```
set.seed(17)
# real weights
weight <- exp(rnorm(4))
share <- weight / sum(weight)
#  Complete Matrix
complete_matrix <- (sapply(weight, runif, n = 10, min = 0))

# the matrix is not completely observed
observed_matrix <- complete_matrix
observed_matrix[sample(x = 40L, size = 25L)] <- NA
```

What approaches can I follow to estimate the share starting from the `observed_matrix`

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to estimate the shares all the stores (including unobserved) out of the weights available in observed matrix?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram I don't mind not estimating the shares of unobserved stores. I want to estimate the shares of all stores that at least have one observation relative to another store.

Comment: i have updated code. Check if this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I beileive this is what you are looking for

```
observed_matrix<- as.data.frame(observed_matrix)
observed_matrix$productsum<- rowSums(observed_matrix, na.rm = TRUE)
prwt<- observed_matrix[-ncol(observed_matrix)]/observed_matrix$productsum
shopshares<- colSums(prwt, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(colSums(prwt, na.rm = TRUE))
shopshares
```

Shares

```
       V1        V2        V3        V4 
0.1554792 0.2053564 0.4112609 0.2279036
```

Comment: I think that central estimate is biased towards shops with observed products on products with few observations. For the central estimate of the share I like better `apply(observed_matrix, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(apply(observed_matrix, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE))`. In any case, the aim of the question is to understand what possibilities do I have to calculate that central estimate and what uncertainty distribution will I have to consider afterwards.